# How to assign the same value to a bus in Xilinx ISE (Schematic)?

Tags: xilinx, ise

How to set all the bits for example in `bus(7:0)` to the value in `net0`?

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **net0** is just a single wire you cannot directly attach it to the **bus(7:0)** because it would logically short all the **bus** lines together. So to be able to do what you want you will need to use a series of eight buffers. The inputs of all the buffers you wire to **net0**. Then the outputs of the buffer wire individually to **bus(7)**, **bus(6)** .... **bus(0)**.

Do note that this brings up a much bigger question here. You are not allowed to create tri-state busses inside most FPGAs. This means that the idea to assign the **net0** value to the whole bus does not make much sense. If indeed that is really really intended then just purge the **bus(7:0)** net entirely and replace it with the **net0** wire.

Comment: I've created buffers, and now it works, I can name each one to bus(0), ..., bus(7). What do you mean by creating tri-state buses? I just wanted to create something like [this](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/sse_c_tap_bit_bus.htm), but with the same bits from one net.

Comment: @user - I mentioned about tri-state busses because it is a very common thing for folks getting into FPGAs to think that they can place multiple drivers onto a bus that then goes off to some other circuit. It was not obvious from your post just what your bus(7:0) actually was. I couldn't tell if it was a destination to some inputs on something or if it was some bus with some other output and some inputs. So the tri-state thing stands as a possible guess as to what was going on. None the less I'm glad that the buffer thing worked out for you. They may very well be optimized away in synthesis.